# Have to log in to Chrome every time it starts after setting up Google Authenticator [OSX]

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-authenticator

A while back, I set up 2FA with Google Authenticator. Now, every time Chrome starts, I need to log in to Chrome again to ensure Chrome sync is running. Is there a way I can trust Chrome to ensure it auto logs in on start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here! https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/uvxl4JIEK5c

> 1. Quit Google Chrome completely.
> 2. In the Mac menu bar at the top of the screen, click Go.
> 3. Select Go to Folder.
> 4. Enter the following directories in the text field, then press Go.
>      `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/`
> 5. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
> 6. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

Blockquote

Comment: I didn't find a *Default* folder, but disconnecting the account(and tick the option to wipe data on machine) and sign in again works for me.